# Unexpected groupby result: some rows are missing

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am facing an issue with transforming my data using Pandas' groupby. I have a table (several million rows and 3 variables) that I am trying to group by "Date" variable.

Snippet from a raw table:

```
Date                 V1          V2
07_19_2017_17_00_06  10           5
07_19_2017_17_00_06  20           6
07_19_2017_17_00_08  15           3
...
01_07_2019_14_06_59  30           1
01_07_2019_14_06_59  40           2
```

The goal is to group rows with the same value of "Date" by applying a mean function over V1 and sum function over V2. So that the expected result resembles:

```
Date                 V1          V2
07_19_2017_17_00_06  15           11  # This row has changed
07_19_2017_17_00_08  15           3
...
01_07_2019_14_06_59  35           3   # and this one too!
```

My code:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).agg({'V1': 'mean', 'V2': 'sum'})
```

The output I am getting, however, is totally unexpected and I am can't find a reasonable explanation of why it happens. It seems like Pandas is only processing data from 01_01_2018_00_00_01 to 12_31_2018_23_58_40, instead of 07_19_2017_17_00_06 to 01_07_2019_14_06_59.

```
 Date                 V1        V2
 01_01_2018_00_00_01  30        3
 01_01_2018_00_00_02  20        4
 ...
 12_31_2018_23_58_35   15       3
 12_31_2018_23_58_40   16       11
```

If you have any clue, I would really appreciate your input. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post sample data in form of CSV to reproduce your situation, that would help.

Comment: provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is based around Pandas not recognizing the date format that I've used. A solution turned out to be quite simple: convert all of the dates into UNIX time format, divide by 60 and then, repeat the groupby procedure.